# Restore GRUB after creation of a NTFS partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a desktop machine (HP Pavilion Slimline s5-1020) that came with Windows 7 and I installed Ubuntu 13.10 beside it. Used to boot into either OS just fine, until I pulled a really stupid trick (>.<)

What I had before Ubuntu 13.10 was my 105 Mb System Part., 600 Gb C:\ Part., 300 Gb Extra Files Part. (used as shared on my network), and the last fraction was HP Restoration.

In order to install Ubuntu, I decided I'd condense my Extra Files into a folder on my C:\ Part. and use that 300 Gb for Ubuntu. This setup worked well until I decided I wanted my Extra Files Part. back...

Booted into Windows 7, I used EaseUS Partition Master to split my 600 Gb C:\ Part. in half and use the new 300 Gb Part. as my Extra Files space. After EaseUS PM rebooted the system, ran pre-OS to set up the partitions, and restarted the system again, I get a message:
"error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> _"

I have no idea what to do from here and I'm thinking that *if*  I can delete that new partition and add it back to C:\, it should work like before and I'll just get an external HDD to run on my network as file storage.

How would I go about deleting my new Part. and adding it back to C:\? I tried GParted in my LiveUSB for Ubuntu (From which I installed) and it can't do anything... It says something about needing the Part. to be unmounted (even though it already appears unmounted). Is there a way I could "boot" EaseUS PM from a CD and use that to revert back?

Is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://superuser.com/q/623941).

Comment: @edwin 
Thank you, but that won't work unless I have a Win7 installation DVD. Only problem is that my computer came with nothing other than a mouse, keyboard, quick start guide, and an instruction book.

Comment: If you cannot get the Windows DVD borrowed, you'll have to install grub as bootloader at very least. In order to do that you need Ubuntu's live media (a USB or DVD), do you have it?

Comment: Ah, no, wait. Read [this help article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader). I think it covers your problem (I mean your problem is that you can't boot Windows, right?.

Comment: @edwin  Yes, I have my LiveUSB from when I installed Ubuntu.   Thanks for that article, I will give it a try as soon as I finish writing this.  BTW: I can't boot into anything on my main HDD. Only my LiveUSB works.
I will edit this comment to say whether or not that article's solution did the trick.

Comment: Had to make a new comment because I'm not allowed to edit comments after 5 minutes of posting them... However, half an hour later (had to perform disk checks :P) and it's working again! Thank you so much edwin! Does the bootloader just look for where the OS partitions are on the drive?

Comment: Yes, you could say that's what the bootloader does in simple terms... I am glad you could solve the problem :) If you want you can answer your own question with the steps you followed for completeness' sake (and possibly helping out someone else).

Answer (score 1):

What worked for my situation was to use [Edwin's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411211/is-there-a-way-i-can-revert-the-creation-of-a-ntfs-partition#comment529525_411211) of using [this Ubuntu wiki help page on restoring GRUB in dual boot with windows Vista/XP/7](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader) and just reinstalling Grub to my HDD from LiveUSB by following the steps on that site. That's all it took!